# How can I write byte[] to socket outputstream and specify the end of file?

Tags: java, client-server

I've googled 2 days straight and I can't find how to do this. I have an open stream between client and server, and client will send a JSON string (encrypted to bytes) to the server each 3 to 5 seconds.

How can I write to the `Socket` `OutputStream` so that I can read each JSON string in the server. I'm guessing I need to specify some kind of end of file or something, but can't find any info on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the stream any more then you can close the stream when done.

Otherwise you will need to specify the length of the content explicitly by for example prefacing the json blob with its total length.

Otherwise you can send a [ascii control byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart) like a null byte or ETX `'\3'` as a delimiter and detect it on the other end. This last one has the problem that you may overflow the input buffer before you get the entire stream or if someone sends malicious input.

Comment: Refusing to use the shift key probably costs you a lot of upvotes.  It certainly cost you one here.

Comment: To Robert's comment, if it were a long, detailed, apparently on point answer with "only" a couple of missed capitalizations, I might upvote it. But this is a "short" answer and I have trouble telling if it is any good. In that context, the missed capitalizations loom large.